# Draw text in frame using CoreText causes crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-text

I am trying to make a method, that will work simmillarry to UILabel but in CoreText, here is what I am trying to do:

```
+(void)drawText:(NSString*)textToDraw
        inFrame:(CGRect)frameRect
       withFont:(NSString *)fontName
   andFontColor:(UIColor *)fontColor
    andFontSize:(float)fontSize{


    CFStringRef fontN = (__bridge CFStringRef)fontName;


    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]
                                         initWithString:textToDraw];

    CTFontRef helvetica = CTFontCreateWithName(fontN, fontSize, NULL);

    [string addAttribute:(id)kCTFontAttributeName
                   value:(__bridge id)helvetica
                   range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];


    [string addAttribute:(id)kCTForegroundColorAttributeName
                   value:(id)fontColor.CGColor
                   range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString((CFAttributedStringRef)string);

    CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
    CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, frameRect);

    // Get the frame that will do the rendering.
    CFRange currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
    CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, NULL);
    CGPathRelease(framePath);

    // Get the graphics context.
    CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Put the text matrix into a known state. This ensures
    // that no old scaling factors are left in place.
    CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);


    // Core Text draws from the bottom-left corner up, so flip
    // the current transform prior to drawing.
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, frameRect.origin.y*2);
    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);

    // Draw the frame.
    CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);

    CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, (-1)*frameRect.origin.y*2);


    CFRelease(frameRef);
    CFRelease(framesetter);

}
```

The problem is that when I run the app it stop at the next line without throwing an exception:

```
CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);
```

**UPDATE:**

Resolved the crash after I removed a few extra lines that are not in this post. But I still need some help in adjusting this method in accepting the number of line and also the line break mode (NSLineBreakByWordWrapping, NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail..)

Comment: Why does it stop? What does it say in the debugger? Are frameRef and currentContext not nil? Alternatively, just in case, maybe the mutable attributed string should be copied to an non-mutable one?

Comment: It stops? Did you set a breakpoint? Is No error at all? A screenshot maybe of the stop with the "Debug Area", and the "Variables View" shown?

Comment: @JacobGorban booth frameRef and currentContext don't appear to be nil, check out this [img](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4f7KioAL2tPU3BEenJkZXZPaXM) and also [this var pic](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4f7KioAL2tPakRxd28tSFU3X2M)

Comment: They images don't show anything suspicious. So what's in the Xcode view code view when it stops? A red line? What's the error? What's the backtrace when it stops?

Answer (score 0):

After figuring out the cause of the crash I added the next line at the beginning of the method:

```
textToDraw = [self getDisplayedStringInFrame:frameRect.size
                                         andFont:[UIFont fontWithName:fontName size:fontSize]
                                       andString:textToDraw];
```

and added this extra method to deal with the `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail` effect in witch I was interested:

```
+ (NSString *) getDisplayedStringInFrame:(CGSize)size andFont:(UIFont *)font andString:(NSString *)str{

    NSString *written = @"";

    int i = 0;
    int currentWidth = 0;
    NSString *nextSetOfString = @"";

    while (1)
    {
        NSRange range;
        range.location = i;
        range.length = 1;

        NSString *nextChar = [str substringWithRange:range];
        nextSetOfString = [nextSetOfString stringByAppendingString:nextChar];

        CGSize requiredSize = [nextSetOfString sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(NSIntegerMax, NSIntegerMax)];
        currentWidth = requiredSize.width;

        if(size.width >= currentWidth && size.height >= requiredSize.height)
        {
            written = [written stringByAppendingString:nextChar];
        }
        else
        {
            break;
        }
        i++;
    }

    written = [written substringToIndex:[written length] - 2];
    written = [written stringByAppendingString:@".."];

    return written;

}
```